# how electrophoretic display like E ink retains particles on top of capsule without power?

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

how electronic ink display retains the particles on top of micro capsule when 
charge on electrode is released or when device is powered off?

Doesnt that make particles loose on the dielectric fluid on capsule after volatge on electrode is removed?

How e ink maintains image even when device is powered off?

I have understood basics of E ink , couldnt understand this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From skimming a few articles and patents on e-ink driver technology, my impression is that the primary reason is that each microcapsule acts as a capacitor.  Once voltage is applied, the particles move to one electrode or the other and remain there because there is no drain path for the charge.  The 'gooiness' of the fluid helps, as evidenced by the typical approach of applying a "shaking pulse" sequence after a certain number of image transitions.  This pulse sequence helps ensure that all the microparticles are freed up to be driven to the appropriate state.
This may or may not be helpful:  http://patents.justia.com/patent/20060170648